# Angular does not recognize Jquery's css function in post-link of a custom directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to learn AngularJS and now I'm playing with custom directives.

As you can see bellow, I'm trying to change to border color of a specific element but this doesn't seem to work when I'm trying to modify it through post-link function.

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('ctr', ['$scope' , function($scope){

}]);

app.directive('mydirective', function(){

  return {
    template: '<strong>HEY</strong>',

    compile: function($tElement , $tAttributes){
      console.log($tAttributes.text + ' @ Compile');
      $tElement.css('border','1px solid black');

      return {
        pre : function($iElement , $scope , $iAttributes){
          console.log($iAttributes.text + ' @ Pre-link');
        },
        post: function($iElement , $scope , $iAttributes){
          console.log($iAttributes.text + ' @ Post-link');

          if( $iAttributes.text === "5"){
              $iElement.css('border','1px solid red');
          }
        }
      };

    },

    controller: function($element , $scope , $attrs){
      console.log($attrs.text + ' @ Controller');
    }
  };

});
```

What angular actually returns is

> TypeError: $iElement.css is not a function

While at a previous time , that css function is used to change thhe border color at compile level function.

Here is also and my html file in case that helps:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Learning AngularJS</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="compile-link.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app">
      <div ng-controller="ctr">
        <div mydirective text="{{i}}" ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]"></div>
      </div>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of the `postLink` function starts with the scope not the element, so `.css()` is not a function because it's not defined on `Scope`. Also, your `preLink` signature is wrong as well, both have to use `scope, elem, attr, ctrl`.

```
compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
  return {
     pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... },
     post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... }
  }
}
```

> Ref.: [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)